# Get list of variable names to find non-camel cased formatting

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I am currently going through a ex-coworkers code to fix any variables that don't have non-camel cased formatting (`myvariable` vs `myVariable`).

This ex-coworker for some reason did camel-casing sometimes, but not all the time, so there is random variables without camel-casing.

I was wondering if there is an efficient way to retrieve/find a list of all variables in a project, so that I can fix this problem, without searching line by line to find variables that are not following our standards.

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and C#.

Comment: If you only need to fix the public variables/properties, you can go through reflection/assembly loading.

Comment: Are you sure it's worth polluting all your diffs and making annotate harder to use for this?

Comment: @DavidArno the problem is that `lowercasevariable` can't be distinguished from `variable` - I don't think R# is clever enough to detect "wrong" variable names in this case.

Comment: annotate is like svn blame - it shows you the changeset that each line last changed in the margin. It's harder to use when there are lots of non-functional changes masking the last "real" change. I'm not saying it's not worth doing, but it's worth considering what will happen in source control.

Comment: @Blorgbeard, thinking about it more, you are right. It would be passible to automatically fix inconsistencies like sometimes PascalCase for methods;  sometimes not, or sometimes `_` at the start of fileds, sometimes not. But `lowercasevariable` can realistically only be fixed reliably via manual inspection as there's too much subjectivity to it.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping for an easy way to get a list of every variable (field, property, and local variable), for manual inspection, so that I may check for formatting, through the Visual Studio IDE, such as how the Code Analysis feature works. (unless there is an easy way to check that programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

I think that, as a commenter suggested, reflection is the way to go - you can get more than the public (IE Protected) variables, but still apparently can't get private ones. Depending on the size of the project this may either take extra or save you some work but it provides some guarantee of accuracy, since I assume you can manually search for private:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ztex2dc.aspx

Comment: You can't get local variables at all. You can only get fields and properties with reflection.